# I would like to categorize the Contribution pages

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, civicampaign

I would like to categorize the Contribution pages. 
How can I use Tags or Groups for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome!  Tags and Groups are concepts that apply to Contacts, not Contribution Pages.  It depends what you want to do with the categorization, but Campaigns may be useful.

If you don't see Campaigns in the top menu, you may need to enable the CiviCampaigns component at `Administer > System Settings > Components`

Comment: Ok, if Campaigns doesn't meet the need, could you describe more of what you want to do?

Comment: I would like to see my contribution pages in two Drupal views. In the first one I want them to be categorized by campaigns. I have very few campaigns and I use them as a "general category".(e.g: winter sports) In the second one I want them to be categorized by Groups/Tags. Those could be more specific categories(e.g: skiing, ice skating). I think hierarchical campaigns would be also very useful for me.

Comment: How about making the more specific ones to be Campaigns and the general category ones to be Campaign Types? - so you would have a Skiing Campaign of type Winter Sports.  Or you could add a custom field to the Campaign to store the general category.

Comment: Thank You! I think adding a custom field to the Campaing will be the solution.